# How do I resolve this encoding problem with ZipInputStream?

Tags: java, encoding, zip

I'm doing a ZipInputStream request on a UTF-8 encoded zip file.

I get the data through OK, but special German characters are coming out wrong.

Using this page ( http://kellykjones.tripod.com/webtools/ascii_utf8_table.html ) I can see that my code is printing out the two individual chars from the UTF8 encoding column.

i.e. ä is UTF 0xC3,0xA4, and I am getting Ã¤ printed out (which are the 0xC3 and 0xA4 chars). Does anyone have any tips?

```
    private InputStream downloadCsv(final String countryCode) {
        final String url = baseUrl + countryCode.toUpperCase() + ".zip";
        final String fileName = countryCode.toUpperCase() + ".txt";

        BufferedInputStream in = null;
        ZipInputStream zIn = null;

        try {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream());
            zIn = new ZipInputStream(in, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            
            ZipEntry zipEntry;
            
            while ((zipEntry = zIn.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                if (zipEntry.getName().equals(fileName)) {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    
                    int c;
                    while((c = zIn.read()) != -1) {
                        sb.append((char)c);
                        System.out.println((char)c + " : " + c);
                    }

                    return new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes());
                }
            }
...
more code
...
```

Comment: The second argument of the constructor `ZipInputStream` specifies the filename encoding, not the file content encoding.  When reading the contents of the file, you need to wrap `zIn` with an `InputStreamReader` to decode the characters.

Comment: Where do you see the German characters come out wrong, in the file names or in the file content?

Comment: Thanks @saka1029 , that worked a treat!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, I fixed this using @saka1029s advice, using an `InputStreamReader`, and would mark it as the accepted answer if I could!

I can't promise my code is the cleanest, but it works now:

```
        BufferedInputStream in = null;
        ZipInputStream zIn = null;
        InputStreamReader zInReader = null;

        try {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream());
            zIn = new ZipInputStream(in);
            
            ZipEntry zipEntry;
            
            while ((zipEntry = zIn.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                if (zipEntry.getName().equals(fileName)) {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    zInReader = new InputStreamReader(zIn);

                    int c;
                    while((c = zInReader.read()) != -1) {
                        sb.append((char)c);
                    }

                    return new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes());
                }
            }
```